# Why does knitr show a warning using auto.arima?

Tags: r, warnings, knitr, forecasting

It appears that running `auto.arima` from the `forecast` package in a `knitr` script always generates a warning - and I don't get this warning when I run it in normal R.

**knitr Markdown Example Code:**

````
```{r}
library(forecast)
```
Spurious warning from forecast and knitr
========================================

The following generates a warning that I don't think is valid

```{r}
summary(auto.arima(WWWusage))
```
````

Produces this:

[image: knitroutput]

Whereas running the following in R normally produces no such warning:

```
> library(forecast)
This is forecast 4.02 

> summary(auto.arima(WWWusage))
Series: WWWusage 
ARIMA(1,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1
      0.6504  0.5256
s.e.  0.0842  0.0896

sigma^2 estimated as 9.793:  log likelihood=-254.15
AIC=514.3   AICc=514.55   BIC=522.08

Training set error measures:
       ME      RMSE       MAE       MPE      MAPE      MASE 
0.3035616 3.1137542 2.4052748 0.2805566 1.9174634 0.5315228
```

Also since this dataset is the example dataset for `auto.arima` I'm inclined to believe that the warning is incorrect (since I suspect a "good" example would be given).

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Did you try writing `{r, warning=FALSE}` ??? See [Here](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) for further details

Comment: @Jilber that just disables the warning.  The warning shouldn't exist in the first place.  I do not have warnings disabled in R.

Comment: +1. I also observed from time to time with the `drc` package the same thing. Running code in R shows no warnings, but when running in knitr some warnings pop up. I can give an working example, however it is to long for a comment.

Comment: See [here](https://gist.github.com/EDiLD/c3f759eeba9287d46405).

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. I'll try to figure out why. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That warning did exist, but was suppressed internally by `forecast`; see `options(warn = -1)` in `forecast:::search.arima`.

`knitr` (actually the `evaluate` package) captures the warnings regardless of the `getOption('warn')` value. In this case, you have to use the `warning=FALSE` option as Jilber suggested.

Comment: This seems to apply also to my drc-example.

Comment: You are correct that the warning was suppressed by `forecast`, but it is not coming from `forecast:::search.arima`. This warning is generated by the unit root test in `tseries::kpss.test` called by `auto.arima`. Unfortunately it generates pointless warnings which I suppress because they bother users unnecessarily.

Comment: @RobHyndman Oh yes, I forgot to mention that; thanks for pointing it out. I did find the source of the warning from `tseries`, which I did not understand (I'm not a time series expert). Did you try to argue with the authors/maintainers about this pointless warning? If they do not agree with you, you can use `suppressWarnings(kpss.test())` to kill the warnings from the root.